# Initialize ArrayList to ArrayList obtained asynchronously

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a new ArrayList instance and initialize it to an arraylist returned by a function. The things I have tried so far do not work.

This is my function which is supposed to return an ArrayList of type . I have tested it and it works perfectly, the contents are read successfully and are stored in the temporary ArrayList created within the function. After filling this ArrayList the function will return it.

```
public ArrayList<User> fetchAllUsers() {

   final ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "http://ecoproduce.eu/api/User",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("Rest response", response.toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    User user = new User();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            user = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i).toString(), User.class);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        allUsers.add(user);
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    return allUsers;
}
```

The problem I face is when I try to declare a new arrayList instance and I try to fill it with the ArrayList returned from the function.

I have tried doing this in the following ways:

Initialize the newly created instance through the constructor:

```
ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>(fetchAllUsers());
```

Initialize the newly created instace of ArrayList through the addAll() function

```
ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
allUsers.addAll(fetchAllUsers());
```

Both of these attempts have left me with an empty ArrayList, how can I solve this?

SOLUTION:

Implemented an interface

```
public interface VolleyCallBack {
    ArrayList<User> onSuccess();
}
```

Changes to the getAllUsers function

```
 public ArrayList<User> getAllUsers(final String email, final VolleyCallBack callBack) {


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "http://ecoproduce.eu/api/User",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("Rest response", response.toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    User user = new User();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            user = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i).toString(), User.class);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        allUsers.add(user);
                    }
                    /*for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++) {
                        if (allUsers.get(i).getEmail().compareTo(email) == 0) {
                            checkSucesfull = true;
                        }

                    }*/
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    return allUsers;
}
```

How I call the function now

```
allUsers = getAllUsers(email, new VolleyCallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public ArrayList<User> onSuccess() {
                        return allUsers;
                    }
                });
```

And the allUsers ArrayList is made global (which is probably not the best solution).

I am still open to improvements on this.

Comment: try ArrayList<User> allUsers = fetchAllUsers();

Comment: Tried this, size is still 0.

Comment: Then your method `fetchAllUsers()` is returning an empty ArrayList....Both of those examples would absolutely work

Comment: debug your code

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. I find this strange because I debugged the function before writing this question and it managed to work. However, now after I debugged it one more time, I see that it is empty. Gonna try to fix my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am getting is you are making an **asynchronous** call to get the list items. which will come sometime later but the initialization will happen as soon as the function gets called. Your ArrayList is in synchronous and the method **fetchAllUsers()** calls for an API to in background thread to fill the items in ArrayList but returns an empty list instantly that's why you are getting empty list.

So in actual you can't initialize some ArrayList which depends on the background thread. you can use callbacks to get the data later but not instantly i hope you are getting my point.

Now what to do:
Depends on what you are trying to achieve but just return nothing from **fetchAllUsers** and on callback of api call do whatever you want to do

```
   public void fetchAllUsers() {
    final ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "http://ecoproduce.eu/api/User",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("Rest response", response.toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    User user = new User();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            user = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i).toString(), User.class);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        allUsers.add(user);
                    }
                   //here your list items are ready to be used, so call some function to consume it 
                  //TODO call to further function
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: I kinda understand what you are saying. How can I fetch the information from the asynchronous call and return it? Actually, I believe that if change the function to type void and create the allUsers arraylist outside of the function the problem will be solved. However, I believe that this is bad programming practice.

Comment: Actually no, I just tried this and the same problem occurs.

Comment: you can't return it but use the callback to trigger the work you want to do after that.  or you use some LiveData to reflect back to data later but again it won't be available instantly where you are initializing the arraylist. At some point you have to use the callback so you one onResponse() just use this function.  If you want to put data before anything then just use some progress to fetch the resullt when result is is there just dimiss the progress and then continue the flow which you want to.

Comment: yes it will happen as told you data is again not there, you can have to use the onResponse to do the further work. i have added a TODO if u can see. use place your code which depends on it

Comment: the flow can't work like this you have to wait for the results and when it is there then just do what you would have done when it was there.

Comment: How can I write a callback to handle this for me? It is my first time working with RESTful API's so I apologise if I am asking for too much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208940/discussion-between-vasko-vasilev-and-vikas-kumar).

Comment: After consulting with vikas kumar in a private chat I have found a way to solve my problem, will update my question to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix using wait and notify. This should work, as the wait call before returning will only proceed after the notify call in the JsonArrayRequest onResponse

```
public ArrayList<User> fetchAllUsers() {

   final ArrayList<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
   final Object notifyObj = new Object();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "http://ecoproduce.eu/api/User",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("Rest response", response.toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    User user = new User();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            user = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject(i).toString(), User.class);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        allUsers.add(user);
                    }
                    sychronized(notifyObj) {
                      notifyObj.notifyAll();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    synchronized(notifyObj) {
      notifyObj.wait();
    }
    return allUsers;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and my application freezes and eventually crashes.